# Add User to ApplicationRole by RoleId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I noticed that when using the `UserManager` class, with the `AddToRole` method, you can only add users to roles by name, not by role ID. Is there a way to do this? The way my system is built, more than one role may have the same name.
I'm looking for something like:

```
UserManager.AddToRole(user.UserId, role.RoleId);
```

where `AddToRole` has the arguments `UserId` and `RoleId`.

Comment: You can NOT have 2 roles with same name in asp.net-identity. "name" column in "roles" table is Indexable.

Comment: Then what's the point of the Id.

Comment: I need the same function. The point is that have Id of the role, and not the name. In order to get the name i need to query the database once more for this info, which is stupid to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your role names should be unique. If you have role names that are the same, how do you differentiate between them?

You could use linq and get the name from the your ID `Roles.Where(r => r.Id == YourRoleId).First().Name` ?

Comment: Using the Id of the Role record, that makes it unique.

Comment: Yes, but lets say you want to add me to a role -> Manger  -> Manger -> Supervisor.   Whats the use of having 2 roles with the same name? It was built like it should. The names should not be the same.

Comment: Because admins of this system can add their own roles with separate permissions, so they may make their own "Supervisor" roles that have different purposes.

Comment: That's going to be one very confusing system for someone that did not set up the roles.

Comment: There's multiple clients, hence the issue with multiple role names.

Comment: Can't you then specify the names like ClientName_RoleName   , Then when you display it in the front end, you just take away the client name and they only see the Role Name?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing now.